# Get the Location which has Max Distance from another Location

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below:

```
Create table Distance
(Loc1ID int not null,
Loc2ID int not null,
Distance int not null)

Insert into Distance values(7 ,8023989 ,1)
Insert into Distance values(11 ,3705843 ,1)
Insert into Distance values(14 ,3700170 ,4)
Insert into Distance values(23 ,1353297 ,5)
Insert into Distance values(23 ,1491303 ,21)
Insert into Distance values(32 ,12514 ,74)
Insert into Distance values(32 ,507545 ,25)
Insert into Distance values(75 ,7971270 ,2)
Insert into Distance values(75 ,4473476 ,1)
Insert into Distance values(75 ,3280411 ,6)
Insert into Distance values(79 ,7100087 ,7)
Insert into Distance values(81 ,7986762 ,2)
Insert into Distance values(84 ,5034 ,31)
Insert into Distance values(84 ,3672346 ,3)
```

I wanted to know the locations which has max distance from Loc1ID. I need the o/p in below format. So, the expected output will be

```
Loc1ID    Loc2ID    Distance

7         8023989   1
11        3705843   1
14        3700170   4
23        1491303   21
32        12514     74
75        3280411   6
79        7100087   7
81        7986762   2
84        5034      31
```

I tried below query, but it is giving me only one record.

```
select top 1 Loc1ID, Loc2ID, max(distance) as Distance from Distance
group by Loc1ID,Loc2ID
order by max(distance) desc
```

How can I proceed here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Loc1ID, Loc2ID, distance from  
(select Loc1ID, Loc2ID, distance, 
rank() over(partition by Loc1ID order by distance desc) rn
from DISTANCE) a where rn =1
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `Loc1ID`, you want the `Loc2ID` that has the maximum distance.  For this, you want to use `row_number()`:

```
select d.Loc1ID, d.Loc2ID, d.distance
from (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by Loc1ID order by distance desc) as seqnum
      from Distance d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want multiple rows when there are duplicates, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.